# Issue with website tagline while viewing in mobile

Tags: css, mobile, title

I am trying to fix my site tagline "Your British Columbia...."  as it is not vertically centred and the letters are not spaced correctly while viewed on a mobile device such as an iphone. 
Below is my current css. Can someone please show me how to fix this with mobile CSS

http://jobspark.ca/

```
#banner-tagline {
color: #FFFFFF;
font-size: 44px;
position: relative;
text-align: center;
z-index: 4;
top: 50%;
font-family: proxima-nova !important;
}
```

[image]

**Update**
Thanks but can you show me how to target the tagline so it changes things just in mobile view

Answer (score 0):

Add CSS

```
line-height: 80px;
```

You can adjust `90px` or `100px` to meet your preference.